# Best way to insert the procedure results to a log table, done within the prc itself?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Ok I have been requested to add a logging process inside the procedure (I didn't come up with this, I don't think its the best thing to do but I am expected to do this at work). I will try to explain with a very simplified example:

```
CREATE TABLE testLog (
  results varchar(200)
);

CREATE TABLE Person (
  PersonID int,
  name varchar(50),
  pAddress varchar(50),
  pPhone varchar(10)
);

INSERT INTO Person
  VALUES (1, 'Anne', '123 St', '1111111111'),
  (2, 'Peter', 'XYZ St', '222222222'),
  (3, 'Jason', '890 St', '3333333333');

-------------------------------------------------
CREATE PROCEDURE SpcDetailsList @inPersonID int
AS
BEGIN
  SELECT TOP 1
    PersonID,
    name,
    pAddress,
    pPhone
  FROM Person p
  WHERE p.PersonID = @inPersonID;
END;
```

Ok, this is what I have - you pass in the parameter values and get something (the actual procedure is confirmed to return always a single row or nothing). But now additionally I have to make the procedure log itself. And this is how I am planning to do it -

```
ALTER PROCEDURE SpcDetailsList @inPersonID int
AS
BEGIN

  DECLARE @PersonID int,
          @name varchar(50),
          @pAddress varchar(50),
          @pPhone varchar(10);

  SELECT
    @PersonID = PersonID,
    @name = name,
    @pAddress = pAddress,
    @pPhone = pPhone
  FROM Person p
  WHERE p.PersonID = @inPersonID;

  INSERT INTO testLog (results)
    VALUES (CAST(@PersonID AS varchar(1)) + ' ' + @name + ' ' + @pAddress + ' ' + @pPhone);

  SELECT
    @PersonID AS PersonID,
    @name AS name,
    @pAddress AS pAddress,
    @pPhone AS pPhone
END
```

The actual procedure can return about 10 to 15 fields. I have to cast them, and replace null for each of them (which I am not doing in this example) then concatenate them (the results needs to be inserted into single field as one string) to insert to log. This doesn't look nice to me. Are there better options to do this exact same thing with good performance?

Edit: I didn't mention here that I have about 10 procedures with different number of outputs which will have to be inserted to the same log table. And the actual log table has more columns including the SP name, parameter values passed in, etc.

Comment: First this one of the most thought out questions I've seen in awhile. Thumbs up. Now, is part of the requirements to keep everything in one column? Because that makes no sense... If you could insert it properly, into separate columns, you could use the OUTPUT clause and not have to worry about all those pesky variables.

Comment: If the need for logging may extend to additional SPs you might want to consider a single logging table with columns for the date/time, caller's Id, SP and version, XML inputs (if any), XML outputs (if any), XML status (e.g. invalid telephone number or discount out of range). Performance is something you need to evaluate in your environment.

Comment: Thank you. One thing I didn't add here is that I have about 10 procedures which will have to be inserted to the same log table. And each of these have different number of variables. That's one of the reasons that the output is concatenated to be one string. The other reason, from what I understand, is this logging is going to be a temporary thing while testing to see something about the outputs, so they don't want elaborate separate column inserts. I think on the calling side they are doing the logging for xml outputs, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have some latitude on what your log looks like, I'd recommend outputting it to XML.  It does all the formatting, casting, etc. for you.  It's also parse-able.  You can also use a temporary table to eliminate your need to declare variables for all the fields.  Something like this:

```
SELECT TOP 1
    PersonID,
    name,
    pAddress,
    pPhone
into #temp
FROM Person p
WHERE p.PersonID = @inPersonID

INSERT INTO testLog VALUES((
SELECT *
FROM #temp
FOR XML AUTO
))

select * 
from #temp
```

Comment: Ok, I will definitely using this. One thing that was bothering me is formatting and casting each output value. But look like I am still stuck with the rest of my approach, meaning I create variables, assign them the values from the select, insert and then output.

Comment: You can use a temporary table to remove the need to declare variables.  I edited the answer to show this approach.